# sonar maven plugin build error, SonarQube version: null

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-maven-plugin

My jenkins builds just started to fail with this message:

```
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.7:sonar (default-cli) @ cividas-core-web ---
[INFO] artifact com.ontimize:ontimize-core: checking for updates from central
[INFO] artifact com.ontimize:ontimize-core: checking for updates from imatia-local
[INFO] artifact com.ontimize:ontimize-core: checking for updates from snapshots
[INFO] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] SonarQube version: null
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.773s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 22 19:49:04 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/193M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7:sonar (default-cli) on project cividas-core-web: null: MojoExecutionException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7:sonar (default-cli) on project cividas-core-web: null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.versioning.ComparableVersion.parseVersion(ComparableVersion.java:354)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.versioning.ComparableVersion.<init>(ComparableVersion.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.versioning.DefaultArtifactVersion.parseVersion(DefaultArtifactVersion.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.versioning.DefaultArtifactVersion.<init>(DefaultArtifactVersion.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.isVersionPriorTo5Dot2(RunnerBootstrapper.java:192)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:84)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Sonar analysis completed: FAILURE
```

What is this all about?

Comment: The hint is here `SonarQube version: null`, and indicates that ComparableVersion (which I wrote btw ;-)) is passed `null`. Is the version declared in your POM?

Comment: No. How can I do that?

Comment: (I know how to explicitly add the sonar maven plugin to my pom, but I can't find anywhere where to place the SonarQube version parameter)

Comment: or do you mean version of the plugin?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_dependencies_Tag). You can override the dependency that way, but you really shouldn't have to. Maybe report a bug to the codehaus mojo project?

Comment: will do. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Kenney - I don't understand why I need to define the sonar version. It was all working fine until 2.7 got released

Comment: Could you confirm that you are using a SQ instance prior to 4.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those interested in *"why?"*, I've done some more digging and what seems to be happening is this:

- [RunnerBootstrapper](https://github.com/mojohaus/sonar-maven-plugin/blob/0b2cfb4394d203234f73808d809937c26c90e068/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar/bootstrap/RunnerBootstrapper.java#L84) attempts to check whether a version is 5.2+:
- First, serverVersion is [retrieved](https://github.com/mojohaus/sonar-maven-plugin/blob/0b2cfb4394d203234f73808d809937c26c90e068/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar/bootstrap/RunnerBootstrapper.java#L81) from a launcher [created in EmbeddedRunner](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-runner/blob/master/sonar-runner-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/runner/api/EmbeddedRunner.java#L250),
- using [IsolatedLauncher creating a proxy](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-runner/blob/master/sonar-runner-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/runner/impl/IsolatedLauncherFactory.java#L94) of [implementation class BatchIsolatedLauncher](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-runner/blob/master/sonar-runner-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/runner/impl/IsolatedLauncherFactory.java#L35)
- which [attempts to read](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-runner/blob/master/sonar-runner-batch/src/main/java/org/sonar/runner/batch/BatchIsolatedLauncher.java#L86) a resource file [`sq-version.txt`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/tree/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/resources) containing the version.

This `sq-version.txt` file is located in [org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-plugin-api](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar/sonar-plugin-api/5.1-RC1), but this dependency is not included (even transitively) in the [sonar-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/dependencies.html). All it references sonar-wise is [org.sonarsource.sonar-runner:sonar-runner-api](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/sonar-runner/sonar-runner-api/2.5-RC1/sonar-runner-api-2.5-RC1.jar).

They seem to [have changed the location and name of the version txt file](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-runner/blob/master/sonar-runner-api/src/main/resources/org/sonar/runner/api/version.txt) but not updated all code. You might get away with manually adding an `sq-version.txt` with content `5.2` (no newline) to the plugin classpath (possibly by updating the plugin jar), or add a dependency on sonar-plugin-api, but these are hacks.

The sonar-maven-plugin 2.6 uses sonar-runner 2.4, which is very different from 2.5 that sonar-maven-plugin 2.7 uses (the groupId for sonar-runner has **changed domains** from `org.codehaus.sonar.runner` to `org.sonarsource.sonar-runner`), so it's best to stick to the v2.6 plugin until they have smoothed out the transition and released a few more versions.

Answer (score 7):

Solved by downgrading the automatically picked latest (2.7) version to an older one (2.4) by adding this code to the plugins section of my `pom.xml`

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: For us, the 2.7 version of the sonar-maven-plugin fails the same way as well, but works with version 2.6. Any idea what is the reason?

Comment: see this if you use jenkins to trigger it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33297231/187950

Answer (score 5):

The way SonarQube server version is passed to `maven-sonar-plugin` has changed in v2.7, along with other things, since it uses now `sonar-runner 2.5`.

There is indeed a bug when using it with SonarQube instances < 4.3, for which I opened the ticket: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MSONAR-131

Note that SQs < 4.5 (current [LTS](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/%20LTS)) are no longer actively supported and there is no guarantee that `sonar-maven-plugin` won't be incompatible with them in other ways due to the new interface exposed by `sonar-runner 2.5`.

For these cases, it is probably best to **lock the maven plugin version to 2.6**, as already suggested.

Comment: I am using the following versions. I have also tried mentioning the version in the goal, but still getting the issue. SonarQube: v 4.5.1 , java: v 1.7.0 , sonar-maven-plugin : 3.0.2 ( default ). Have also tried mentioning older version in the goal as : org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0.6:sonar

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem at work today, we automatically use the latest version for maven and sonar plugins. It wasn't easy to find the problem at first.

The answer elcodedocle has given is correct, but i would like to add for those that use maven with sonar in an automated fashion that this is a solution aswell:

**org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar**

This way it runs on the older version 2.6 and i can confirm that it works.

There is probably a bug in 2.7 and i hope it gets fixed soon. This was our error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven plugin:2.7:sonar (default-cli) on project (projectName): Unable to determine structure of project. Probably you use Maven Advanced Reactor Options with a broken tree of modules. "(projectName)" is orphan -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**EDIT:**
Take a look at this post for some more information: [Jenkins Sonar plugin suddenly stops working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297230/jenkins-sonar-plugin-suddenly-stops-working?lq=1)

Here is explained that the new version, 2.7, of the plugin is no longer compatible with java 6 projects. You can also find an explanation about how to fix it in Jenkins if you are not familiar with it. (my explanation was a bit short)

Answer (score 0):

This is a hint:

```
[INFO] SonarQube version: null
```

Later in the code, Maven tries to parse this version number and fails. The source code is here: https://github.com/mojohaus/sonar-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar/bootstrap/RunnerBootstrapper.java

From the [source of the SonarQube runner](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-runner/blob/master/sonar-runner-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/runner/api/EmbeddedRunner.java), this is backed by a properties instance. So maybe the code couldn't access the server or the server isn't sending this data back. Hard to tell.

What I can see is that the code changed in 2.5. That's probably why 2.4 still works. See here how to nail down the versions: [Jenkins Sonar plugin suddenly stops working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297230/jenkins-sonar-plugin-suddenly-stops-working/33297231#33297231)

Comment: I would say that the server does not send the version back. As far as I understand, the Sonarqube server version is queried thanks to "BatchIsolatedRunner.getVersion" https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-runner/blob/master/sonar-runner-batch/src/main/java/org/sonar/runner/batch/BatchIsolatedLauncher.java

Comment: Quite possible. I don't have a local setup, so I can't debug ATM.

Answer (score 0):

Discover the appropriate plugin version for you running sonar installation.

E.g.
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar

This plugin version will not work against the latest sonar release but will work fine against a 4.1.2.